# How to change language?

Tags: multi-language

Sorry for this complete newbie question, but I googled it and cannot find this simple information.

I just installed Wordpress today. 
Right now all text on my Wordpress Blog is in English: "Home", "About", "Comments", etc.

How can I change the language?

---

Update: I am actually not out of the woods yet with this one.
I have:

1. located the fr_FR.mo file and copied it into a new directory '/wp-content/languages/'
2. Modified the wp-config.php file to have the following line into it:

> define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');

Unfortunately I still get the interface in English.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Ok, I found the problem: I was adding the line:

> define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');

when in fact there was *already* another line of code:

> define ('WPLANG', );

which was probably overriding my bit of code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you also still get the admin in english? or only the public part?

Comment: Hi sorich87, I get both the admin and the public parts in English. I wish to have the public part in French. Admin can stay in English.

Comment: Ravi que cela fonctionne maintenant! :)

Comment: Merci sorich87 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Installing WordPress in Your Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language) in the codex.

Comment: Thank you. That looks way more complicated than I expected. Manual editing of a wp-config.php ? I was expecting a simple menu, and to just select the language.

Comment: It seems in 2011 they briefly offered a drop-down, but now in 2012, in both 3.4(.1-.3) and 3.5(beta 1) they're back to manual editing?

Answer (score 1):

Most of those things can be changed in your template files.

But you should also read -> http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language